# connection problem

Tags: c#, database

how to write this script

```
if (con.Open == true) ;
{ 
   totalv.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
else
{
   con.Open();
   totalv.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: looks C#-ish enough to me - except that you have a semicolon after the if line, which I think is a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the main problem is due to the semi-colon at the end of your `if`:

```
if (con.Open == true) ;
```

That's basically terminating the `if` statement as you've just got a block after it... which means the `else` has nothing to refer to. So the most minimal change would be to:

```
if (con.Open == true)
{ totalv.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
else
{
    con.Open();
    totalv.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

However, this is more simply written as:

```
if (!con.Open)
{
    con.Open();
}
totalv.ExecuteNotQuery();
```

Next problem - you're trying to use `Open` as both a property and a method. I suspect you want something like this:

```
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    con.Open();
}
totalv.ExecuteNotQuery();
```

However, I would agree with Pranay that it would be better to just open and close the connection each time you need it, and let connection pooling deal with the physical network connection. Why are you dealing with a potentially-closed connection at all?

Comment: their basically i dont want to open multi connection.open
its make error to my site

Comment: @azeem: You should really work on fixing that then - using the built-in connection pool is the idiomatic way to handle database connections in .NET. Keeping a single connection open is going to be really error-prone.

Comment: how to  using the built-in connection pool
can you suggest me

Comment: @azeem: Exactly as per pranay's code - open the connection, close it. The actual network connection will be pooled.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do it : use of using statement with connection object

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(commandString, cn))
    {
        cn.Open();
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```